# Scala Process Terminal Output

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

I'm using the Scala (2.10.3) Process object to run commands.  The [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) show me how to run a command and then capture the standard output, but I'm running [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and want to see upload progresses.  How can I capture the output as if the command were running in a terminal?

**Solution:**

```
"s3cmd sync --recursive --delete-removed --progress local/ s3://remote" ! ProcessLogger(line => log.info(line))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line at a time:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger

for vanilla stdout

https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/S3/Progress.py